# Can you use another Profile Builder shortcodes through advanced custom fields

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields, profiles

I have some custom fields tied to a my page. I would like to use Profile builder shortcodes to introduce a login and registration functionality to it.

So far the raw shortcode seems only to popup on the page and nothing else.

Is there another way to implement the login and registration or do I need to create a workaround using the standard Wordpress dashboard?